# Linq Query C# ( Multiple Occurrences in String array)

Tags: c#, linq

Guys I know this might be a naive Question but i got to ask.
I have array of string 
`List<string> lstPets = new List<string> { "dog", "cat","horse","parrot" };`

And a string

`string paragraph = "This is a test script to test whether a dog exists or not";`

Now I have to write a linq query to find whether any occurrence of "lstPets" in "paragrah".

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Please check one line answer                                                                  bool obj = lstPets.Any(row => paragraph.Contains(row));

Comment: bool obj = lstPets.Any(row => paragraph.Split(' ').Contains(row)); Please apply logic for removing multiple space to single space, people came here for help not for just enjoyment

Comment: Thanks Ghulam...your logic also does the trick...  :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var lstPets = new List<string> { "dog", "cat","horse","parrot" };

string paragraph = "This is a test script to test whether a dog exists or not";
```

---

```
var containsAny = lstPets.Any(paragraph.Contains);
```

Or maybe more tolerant:

```
var containsAny = lstPets.Any(pet => paragraph.Contains(pet, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sentenceQuery = from item in paragraph
                        let w = item .Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' },                                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  
                        where w.Distinct().Intersect(IsPets).Count() == IsPets.Count()  
                        select item ;         
    foreach (string str in sentenceQuery)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(str);  
    }
```

Comment: are you sure thats C# syntax code... because apparently this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try Code

```
var countres = lstPets.Where(c => paragraph.Contains(c)).ToList().Count() > 0 ? true : false;
```